# Can we delete name of a variable in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to know if it is possible that for example I defined `int temp` then later, I define `temp` as a `float`.

I mean I want to use the name "temp" more than once in a `.cpp` file. Is this possible? If it's possible, how?

edit: I meant in the same scope.

Comment: Show your code. You can have two different blocks each having its own `temp` variable (you might make it `static`  to keep its value from one call to the next one of the same routine).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you can't declare two variables with the same name in the same **scope**. Their scopes must be different.

Like this:

```
int temp; // this is global

struct A
{
    int temp; // this is member variable, must be accessed through '.' operator
};

int f1()
{
    int temp; //local temp, though the global one may by accessed as ::temp
    ...
}

int f2()
{
    int temp; //local

    // a new scope starts here
    {
        int temp; //local, hides the outer temp
        ...
    }

    // another new scope, no variable of the previous block is visible here 
    {
        int temp; // another local, hides the outer temp
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be more informative without the `if` and `else`: braces are allowed by themselves, with no extra flow control, just for the purpose of introducing a new scope.

Answer (score 3):

There is no concept of deleting the name of a variable in C++.  However, the lifetime and visibility of automatic variables is limited to the scope that they're declared in.  So you could do something like the following:

```
void foo()
{
    {
        int temp;
        ...
    }

    {
        float temp;
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible to use the same name for different types and variables within a .cpp file.  It can even be done within the same function.  The only requirement is that the names be in different scopes.

```
void LegalExample() { 
  int temp = 42;
  if (...) {
    float temp;
    ...
  }
}

void IllegalExample() {
  int temp;
  float temp;
}
```

In general though it's considered bad practice to declare variables of the same name within the same function.  It usually just leads to developer confusion and places where you really think you need the same named variable twice is typically an indication that you need 2 separate functions

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that's possible. You could put two variables named temp in different namespaces.

Also you could use Hungarian notation like so:

```
void foo()
{
    float fTemp;
    int iTemp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid this situation, as a variable should do only one thing. Even if you use different scopes over time you might get confused. It is better to define several varibales with different names, instead of reusing one.

Think about what you want to acchieve with this variable and name it correspondingly.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your scope. You can define a variable name once in a certain scope. You cannot change the type of that variable.

But you can use the same variable name in other scopes for example other methods in your cpp file.